# Como puedo arrastrar un marker y obtener la lat y lng?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocalización

Buen día estimados.
Me podrían guiar o dar alguna sugerencia de como puedo mover el marker cuando arrastro el mapa, y al momento de que el marker se mueva obtenga su nueva lat y lng. 
alguien de buen corazón que me guié.

Este es mi código que me calcula la posición actual, (código segmentado)

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    miUbicacion();
}

    private void agregar_marker(double lat, double lng) {
            LatLng coordenadas = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            CameraUpdate miUbicacion = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordenadas, 15);
            if (marcador != null) marcador.remove();
            marcador = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(coordenadas).title("Mi Ubicación Actual")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_user)));
            mMap.animateCamera(miUbicacion);
        }


        //Método que obtiene la lat y lng de mi posición actual
        private void actualizaUbicacion(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                latitud = location.getLatitude();
                longitud = location.getLongitude();
                agregar_marker(latitud, longitud);
            }
        }


   //Objeto LocationListener, para estar pendiente a cualquier cambio de localidad por el GPS
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                actualizaUbicacion(location);
            }


private void miUbicacion() {
        //permiso

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        actualizaUbicacion(location);
        location
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero agrega la propiedad de arrastrable como `true` al marcador:

```
 .icon(...).draggable(true));
```

Y puedes usar estos métodos, es obvio lo que hacen según el nombre. Te muestro la forma de obtener la latitud y la longitud:

```
@Override
public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "POSICION INICIAL "+ "Marker " + marker.getId() + " Draggable" + marker.getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ON "+"Marker " + marker.getId() + " Draggable" + marker.getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
    double punto = marker.getPosition();
    double lati = marker.getPosition().latitude;
    double longi = marker.getPosition().longitude;
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "POSICION FINAL "+"Marcador " + marker.getId() +"\n"+ " latitud " + lati+"\n"+ " longitud "+ longi, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CLICKADO " + marker.getId() + " Draggable" + marker.getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
 }
```

Comment: Estimado muchas gracias por responder, al parecer si me funciono, pero lo que quiero hacer es cuando muevo el mapa el marker tambien se mueva, de lo investigue, lo pude hacer con el evento setOnCameraIdleListener, a lo que muevo el marker al rato regresa a la posicion actual y parpadea. que podra ser.

Comment: mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraIdle() {
                LatLng latLng = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
                CameraUpdate miUbicacion = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15);
                if (marcador != null) marcador.remove();
                marcador = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)                     .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_user)));
                mMap.animateCamera(miUbicacion);
            }
        });

Comment: si quieres mover el mapa y actualizar el marcador al hacer click en el mapa, agrega mMap.clear(); antes de agregar el marker (marcador = mMap.addMarker ...), quita if (marcador != null) marcador.remove();

Comment: Estimado muchas gracias, logré mover el marker cuando muevo el mapa y me obtiene las lat y lng, pero ahora mi problema el marker se regresa automxaticamente a la ubicación actual, osea muevo el marker hacia otro lado y luego se regresa